# How to resolve System.AccessViolationException C#

Tags: c#, leadtools-sdk

I am getting an error in c# when using leadtools `advantage.dll`

> System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory.

it seems that it occurs randomly.

Comment: Please include your code in question that you tried.

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Do you get these errors while performing OCR? 
If yes, can you duplicate the same issue using one of LEADTOOLS pre-complied OCR demos shipped with the SDK (for example, our v19 CSOcrMultiEngineDemo_Original.exe demo)?

After testing this issue with the OCR demo, the next thing to verify with such problems is whether you have the latest build of the DLLs for your version of LEADTOOLS. To do that, send your toolkit serial number to support@leadtools.com and specify the build number (file properties version info) of Leadtools.Forms.Ocr.Advantage.dll.

If the latest build doesn't solve the problem, and since it is random at your side, we need to find a way to narrow down its possible causes as follows:

1. You should determine which LEADTOOLS function is being called when the error happens. You could check the stack trace or add debugging messages or log entries in your code.
2. Provide us with a sample image that shows this issue, along with details on how you tested.
3. Which version of LEADTOOLS (17.5, 18, 19, etc.) shows this error and what is the build number of your DLLs?
4. Which version of Windows (7, 8.1, 10, etc.) that you use? And is it 32-bit or 64-bit?

If your images contain confidential information, we can sign a Non-Disclosure Agreement (NDA) for the files you send. If this is needed, have your legal department prepare the agreement and send it to support@leadtools.com.